# Snowflake: calculate seconds difference between date and start of that date

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let’s say I have a table that has one column as `timestamp ntz`. I want to perform a `select` that calculates the number of seconds difference between that moment in the table vs the start of that date. For pure timestamp type I can just use the `timediff` function:

```sql
select timediff(second, 
    ‘2022-01-01 00:00:05’::timestamp_ntz, 
    ‘2022-01-01 00:00:00’::timestamp_ntz
)
```

Which returns 5.

How can I do it with a value in a table, for example:

```sql
select timediff(second, my_date, my_date_startofdate)
```

Where `my_date_startofdate` will be converted to that day but at time `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `date_trunc`.  This function takes a timestamp or date and truncates it to whatever element you want.  So, if you take your timestamp column and trunc it day, it removes the time elements and gives you the beginning of the day.

```
select timediff(second, date_trunc('day',my_date), my_date)
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html